# Display textfield as clickable link

Tags: 7, navigation

I am trying to make textfields clickable so it would appear as link. What would be the best solution for this? I tried **Link** module, but it is not what I am looking for. This is how I got my textfield written:

```
$form['element4']['link4'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('link for 4th div'),
        '#description' => t('your link'),
    );
```

I need for it to stay textfield as user can input his value, but I want it to be displayed lets say in blue color and so that you could click on it. How could I do this in the most simple way?

Comment: Do you want to make field label as clickable and field value as textfield?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the [#ajax](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x#ajax) property of the Form API. Have a look at this page to find the answer to your question:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1256510